# Display multiple SQL records using JS to parse a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, mysqli

I want to use JS/JQuery/PHP/MySQLi to auto-generate an HTML table to fill a div on a page which also includes a div allowing the user to enter search criteria. Eg: Enter a range of dates, click a button to $.post those dates to a PHP file that queries a MySQLi table and returns a multi-dimensional array to JS which then parses that array as it builds the HTML.

So from the user's perspective he enters a start date and stop date and, elsewhere on the same page, he sees a list of all bookings that were made between those 2 dates.

For code management purposes I want to keep my JS script as a separate file referenced in the HTML page header and my PHP script as a separate file referenced from the JS script.

My JS script looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var startDate = new Date (2017,11,25);
    var stopDate = new Date (2017,11,31);
    displayBookings = function(startDate, stopDate) {
        $.post("php/getBookings.php", {
        startDate: startDate, 
        stopDate: stopDate
        },
        function(data){
            html = "<table>";   
            var i, j, result = JSON.parse(data); 
            while (i=0, i <= result.length, i++) {
               while (j=0, j <= result[i].length, j++) {          
                    html+= "<tr><td>"+result[i][j]+"</td></tr>";
                }
            }
            html += "</table>";
            $('#bookings').html(html);
        });
    };
});
```

My php script ('getBookings.php') looks like this:

```
<?php
$startDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST["startDate"]));
$stopDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST["stopDate"]));
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","userid","password","database");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$stopDate'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $newArray[$i]['reference'] = $row['reference'];
    $newArray[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $newArray[$i]['price'] = $row['price'];
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($newArray);
?>
```

My HTML code includes:

```
<button onClick='displayBookings()'>Press</button>
<div id="bookings"></div>
```

But when I press the button I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

I'm a beginner so I know I've probably made some basic mistake. Can anyone help?

Comment: Well use the debugger to look at what `data` actually is when its returned

Comment: And also, there is no need of parsing data into json format

Comment: You can press F12, that will open the developer tools. It has a network tab where you can see your xhr (xml http request). There you should be able to see the content. Could you post the content of that or at least part of it?

Comment: It's a very long piece of content. Here's the first few characters. I have no idea what it is telling me.        ;!function(){var t=0,e=function(t,e){return"function"!=typeof t||t.replaced?t:(e.replaced=!0,e)};if("undefined"!=typeof CustomEvent&&"function"==typeof window.dispatchEvent)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the wrong response there. I updated my answer, can you tell me what the console.log logs out?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely `while (i=0, i <= result.length` should probably be: `while (i=0, i < result.length`, the same goes for j.

It probably would be better to use `map` or `reduce`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var startDate = new Date(2017, 11, 25);
  var stopDate = new Date(2017, 11, 31);
  displayBookings = function (startDate, stopDate) {
    $.post("php/getBookings.php", {
      startDate: startDate,
      stopDate: stopDate
    },
      function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2));
        html = "<table>" +
          data.map(
            row=>{
              row.map(
                item=>`<tr><td>${item}</td></tr>`
              ).join("");
            }
          ).join("") + "</table>";
        $('#bookings').html(html);
      });
  };
});
```

In case your PHP returns an object with properties as JSON then you could try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var startDate = new Date(2017, 11, 25);
  var stopDate = new Date(2017, 11, 31);
  displayBookings = function (startDate, stopDate) {
    $.post("php/getBookings.php", {
      startDate: startDate,
      stopDate: stopDate
    },
      function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2));
        html = "<table>" +
          Object.keys(data).map(
            key=>{
              Object.keys(data[key]).map(
                rowKey=>`<tr><td>${data[key][rowKey]}</td></tr>`
              ).join("");
            }
          ).join("") + "</table>";
        $('#bookings').html(html);
      });
  };
});
```

The problem with object is that there is no specification about the order, for example:

```
Object.keys({
  first: 1,
  second:2
});
```

Will usually produce `["first","second"]` but there is no guarantee it will.

So it probably will be best to use the first code block but change your PHP to do:

```
$newArray = array()
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $newArray[$i] = array(
    $row['reference'],
    $row['name'],
    $row['price']
  );
}
```

I assume that your original `data.map is not a function` was not caused by php not converting arrays correctly so with that PHP you can use the JavaScript as in the first code block (`data.map` and `row.map`)

Comment: Thanks but tried that and it tells me that Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function?

Comment: I also tried removing the JSON.encode and corresponding JSON.parse methods at both ends but no good. Is my php script correct?

Comment: @JulesGru you should not remove the `json_encode` in PHP, don't know what the `JSON.encode` is since it is not in any of the code you posted but I assume you meant `json_encode`in PHP.

Comment: Thanks HMR. I accidentally mixed up the JS and PHP format of this method. Still can't get this to work but will keep trying!

Comment: @JulesGru I updated the answer, you should probably make a small change to your PHP.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I can build $newArray with the PHP array command instead. I will give that a go - thanks.